# Como utilizar o react-select integrado com Unform sem typescript?

Tags: javascript, react, react-select

Estou estudando React e em particular uma biblioteca para criar formulários que é o Unform, estava conseguindo criar os components até que me deparei com um problema. O select está integrado com a biblioteca react-select porém o exemplo da documentação está em typescript e meu cli do react está com o padrão js, logo o código apresenta algumas diferenças que eu não consigo entender e ajustar, gostaria de saber como esse trecho de código ficaria sem o typescript.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { OptionTypeBase } from 'react-select';
import Select, { Props as AsyncProps } from 'react-select/async';
import { useField } from '@unform/core';

interface Props extends AsyncProps<OptionTypeBase> {
  name: string;
}

const AsyncSelect: React.FC<Props> = ({ name, ...rest }) => {


const selectRef = useRef(null);
  const { fieldName, defaultValue, registerField, error } = useField(name);
  useEffect(() => {
    registerField({
      name: fieldName,
      ref: selectRef.current,
      getValue: (ref: any) => {
        if (rest.isMulti) {
          if (!ref.select.state.value) {
            return [];
          }
          return ref.select.state.value.map(
            (option: OptionTypeBase) => option.value,
          );
        }
        if (!ref.select.state.value) {
          return '';
        }
        return ref.select.state.value.value;
      },
    });
  }, [fieldName, registerField, rest.isMulti]);
  return (
    <Select
      cacheOptions
      defaultValue={defaultValue}
      ref={selectRef}
      classNamePrefix="react-select"
      {...rest}
    />
  );
};
export default AsyncSelect;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O TypeScript adiciona tipos para variáveis, classes e funções. Basicamente se vc tirar os tipos funciona a mesma coisa no JS.

```js
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { OptionTypeBase } from 'react-select';
import Select, { Props as AsyncProps } from 'react-select/async';
import { useField } from '@unform/core';

const AsyncSelect = ({ name, ...rest }) => {


const selectRef = useRef(null);
  const { fieldName, defaultValue, registerField, error } = useField(name);
  useEffect(() => {
    registerField({
      name: fieldName,
      ref: selectRef.current,
      getValue: ref => {
        if (rest.isMulti) {
          if (!ref.select.state.value) {
            return [];
          }
          return ref.select.state.value.map(
            option => option.value,
          );
        }
        if (!ref.select.state.value) {
          return '';
        }
        return ref.select.state.value.value;
      },
    });
  }, [fieldName, registerField, rest.isMulti]);
  return (
    <Select
      cacheOptions
      defaultValue={defaultValue}
      ref={selectRef}
      classNamePrefix="react-select"
      {...rest}
    />
  );
};
export default AsyncSelect;
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, estou começando agora nesse mundo do JS e tudo é muito novo para mim.